# Изменение переменной через модальное окно Delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, изменить значение переменной в основном окне через модальное.

В основном окне создал переменную mes типа String, в модальном окне пытаюсь передать новые значения переменной mes через unit1.mes := 'Какой то текст';

Ошибки никакой нет, а вот изменяться переменная отказывается.

И еще вопрос: возможно ли изменять не только глобальные переменные?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1) Проверил. Работает. Переменной присваивается значение.

2) Насколько мне известно, вы можете использовать глобальные переменные модуля в других модулях, если эти переменные объявлены в разделе interface.
Локальные же переменные на то и локальные, увы.

Comment: Странно, сейчас создал две формы, в implementation добавил uses Unit1 и Unit2 соответственно. В Unit1 создал глобальную переменную text:String, в unit два указал unit1.text := 'Какой то текст', к примеру:  
Showmessage(text);  
И при действии текст в Showmessage не изменяется.

Или же я не правильно присваиваю значение переменной? О_о

Comment: Давайте по порядку.
В Unit1 в разделе Interface объявлена переменная text.
В Unit2 происходит изменение переменной Unit1.text и вывод ShowMessage(Unit1.text)? Или все таки ShowMessage(text)?

Comment: Все верно, просто нужно изменить значение глобальной переменной, объявленной в Unit1, но изменить это значение нужно со второго модального окна, исполняться переменная будет с первого окна Unit1.

Теперь вопрос, как изменить глобальную переменную, объявленную в разделе Interface(Unit1), со второго модального окна (Unit2)?   
В Unit2 переменную видно, пишу в XE6.

Comment: Эм, прочитайте, пожалуйста, мой вопрос.
Вы во втором модуле вызываете функцию ShowMessage с каким именно параметром? Text или Unit1.Text?

Comment: Эм, ShowMessage я вызываю с первого Unita, поэтому, как я вызываю ShowMessage со второго Unita, сказать я вам, к сожалению, не могу. Я же написал: второй unit нужен только для изменения значения, все остальное происходит в unit1.

Comment: @StereoVex, код в студию, пожалуйста.